# Reading file's content downloaded from dropbox -objective-c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, readfile, dropbox-api

I want to read and print the file's content which downloaded from dropbox but my "readFile" method prints null. I am sure the file is downloaded successfully.

```
-(void)download
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"File.txt"]];


    [[self restClient] loadFile:@"/File.txt" intoPath:filePath];

}
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedFile:(NSString*)localPath
       contentType:(NSString*)contentType metadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata {

    [self readFile:@"File.txt"];
    NSLog(@"File loaded into path: %@", localPath);
}

-(void)readFile:(NSString *)fileName
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fileNameData=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",fileName];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileNameData];
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

    NSError *error;

    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}
```

and this is output:

```
---------******** CONTENT OF THE DOWNLOADED FILE *********------------(null)
```

I updated my code for capture erorr and I am getting this error from stringWithContentsOfFile:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=261 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 261.)" UserInfo=0x1669c2b0 {NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Applications/11B10727-E372-1147-26BD-1D24S60B8E54/Docume‌​nts/File.txt, NSStringEncoding=4} 2013-08-05 22:06:03.229 DBApp[496:60b]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your code is reading a file called "File.txt" rather than the actual file that was downloaded from Dropbox. Am I missing something?

**EDIT**

Based on the comments below, it looks like the error is 261, related to string encoding. You might want to try a different encoding or ensure that the text file is encoded the way you expect it to be.

Comment: Actual file name is File.txt too, the file downloaded from dropbox

Comment: You should breakpoint where the file is read and written. I think your download is not working.

Comment: So you see "File loaded into path: File.txt" in the log? You might also try capturing the error from `stringWithContentsOfFile` in case there's something useful there.

Comment: I am getting this error from stringWithContentsOfFile: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=261 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 261.)" UserInfo=0x1669c2b0 {NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Applications/11B10727-E372-1147-26BD-1D24S60B8E54/Documents/File.txt, NSStringEncoding=4}
2013-08-05 22:06:03.229 DBApp[496:60b]

Comment: The file contains some non-english chars, I deleted these and it works great now.. thank you very much  @smarx...